# Angular Strict Di does not throw error whenever a controller uses implicit annotation within Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was facing the following issue with minified angularJS 1.x application

`Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n`

As per the suggestions on other related questions i added strict dependency injection while bootstrapping our application as follows

`angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name], {
        strictDi: true
    });`

Even after i added this i was not facing any issues when my application was running with non-minified code, But when i minified the code i was facing unknown provider error. As per the documentation in angularjs will throw error if there is any implicit annotation when using strict dependency injection. But somehow it was not doing it.

I finally found that the issue was occuring in one of the directive which had a controller with implicit annotation for $scope as follows

```
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.directive('myTabs', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    controller: function MyTabsController($scope) {
      var panes = $scope.panes = [];

      $scope.select = function(pane) {
        angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
          pane.selected = false;
        });
        pane.selected = true;
      };

      this.addPane = function(pane) {
        if (panes.length === 0) {
          $scope.select(pane);
        }
        panes.push(pane);
      };
    },
    templateUrl: 'my-tabs.html'
  };
})
```

The issue got resolved after i used Inline Array Annotation.

I just wanted to know why strict di did not throw any errors? Should i make any other changes in my code?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple angular application with strict dependency injection using both manual bootstrap and automatic bootstrap approach.

Plunker links are as follows:

Manual Bootstrap: https://plnkr.co/edit/9QoKpzzjvFHMT1ZdTIoy?p=preview

Automatic Bootstrap: https://plnkr.co/edit/kBXOpY?p=preview

What I found out was in both cases if the controller has implicit annotation for dependency then  angular 
throws error on bootstrap as follows:

```
angular.js:12798 Error: [$injector:strictdi] ScrollDirectiveController is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.12/$injector/strictdi?p0=ScrollDirectiveController
    at angular.js:68
    at Function.annotate [as $$annotate] (angular.js:3825)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4548)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:9435)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8540)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7975)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:8571)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7975)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7978)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7855)
```

The issue in our application was that the controller definition was using Inline Array Annotation without specifying any dependency as shown in the code below:

```
function scrollDirective($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      callback: '&scrollDirective'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         //some code here
    },
    controller: [function ScrollDirectiveController($scope) {
      console.log("controller loaded!!");
    }]
  };
```

I have also created a plunk for the same : https://plnkr.co/edit/nkzvmeoeV9ARHVMzWHFI?p=preview

In this case angular does not throw any errors